# Change MySQL Username with mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, mysqladmin

In shell, I can change my MySQL password using:

mysqladmin -uroot password NewPassword

Is it possible to change my MySQL username using mysqladmin, too?

Comment: it must be mysqladmin or query also suitable?

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible using mysqladmin (no queries).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rename user with *mysqladmin* command.
Use *mysql* `RENAME USER` statement to do this.
see: `$ man mysqladmin`

Answer (score 0):

you can able to change username, with this commands

use mysql;
update user set user='newusername' where user='oldusername';
flush privileges